# Eligosource / eventsourced Library after Scala upgrade from 2.10.0 to 2.13.10 version

Tags: scala, akka

I have a Scala / Akka project that uses Scala version 2.10.0 and I'm looking to upgrade it to version 2.13.10, but I found that one of the libraries it uses is  eligosource-eventsourced which I saw that is compatible up to 2.10.2 Scala version, so I was wondering if do you know any alternative for replacing this library? or is there anyway to use it even with the Scala Upgrade? Thank you and I look forward for your comments.

I'm working in a OSGI environment so I was pretending to find a way, if possible to make the bundle point to the new Scala version, but also I know that there are big chances for it fail, due that the library is at the end compiled with 2.10.0 version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Haven't worked with [eligosource-eventsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced), but looks like the last commit was on **Dec 12, 2013**. It's not marked as archived, but I guess it's not being maintained anymore.

Since you are working with [akka](https://akka.io/), you can consider to use [akka-persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html), which is the module that akka offers for event sourcing.

I'm only suggesting `akka-persistence` because you said that you are working on an `akka environment`. Of course you can find more libs for event sourcing in Scala, each one with pros and cons. Everything will depend on the context of the project. but that could lead to an opinion based discussion which is something that the community try to avoid.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Gastón, thanks a lot for your kind response, I'll give it a try to akka-persistence. Best Regards

Comment: Sure, no problem. Feel free to ask a more specific question if you have an issue dealing with `akka-persitence`, or any other topic, adding as much context as you can. The article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) gives some tips on what you can ask and how you can make your question good. If you think that this answers is good enough, mark it as the correct one. Best regards